# Типизация замыкания

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

```
const createSuffixName = <N extends string>(name: N) => {
  return <S = undefined>(suffix?: S): S extends string ? `${N}/${S}` : N => {
    return suffix ? `${name}/${suffix}` : name;
  };
};

const test = createSuffixName<'test'>('test');
const testName1 = test();
// testName1 type = "test"
const testName2 = test<'suffix'>('suffix');
// testName2 type = "test/suffix"
```

тут ошибка:

```
return suffix ? `${name}/${suffix}` : name;
```

--

```
TS2322: Type 'N | `${N}/${string}`' is not assignable to type 'S extends string ? `${N}/${S}` : N'.
  Type 'N' is not assignable to type 'S extends string ? `${N}/${S}` : N'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'S extends string ? `${N}/${S}` : N'.
```

Не знаю как ее пофиксить так, чтобы поведение осталось такое же.

Есть у кого идеи как это пофиксить?

Comment: вы хотите литеральный тип генерировать? Сомневаюсь, что это так будет работать.